# Best javascript event to listen for to to avoid affecting pagespeed hit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pagespeed

I want to preform some AJAX requests and other actions after the page is loaded, but using both `window.onload` and `$(document).ready()` seems to both affect the google pagespeed score of the page as well as the "load" time in the browsers devtools.

Using something like scroll or mouse movement avoids this problem, but neither of those are guaranteed to happen.

What would be a good js event to listen for to prevent that preformance hit above while still doing the actions on every page load by a user? I don't mind if those actions didn't happen at all when a bot visits (scrapes) the site.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot avoid it, the pagespeed insights tool uses Lighthouse, which actually loads your website in a browser emulating a mobile and a desktop device and slowly scrolls to the bottom of it.

Then it captures requests on the network layer.

There is no way to "cheat" it.

If you need more clarification try to run some examples with puppeteer software.